# Faster alternative to egrep in shell scripting or Perl

Tags: perl, shell, grep

`$logFile` has size 20GB

```
$RAW_FILTER=pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5|....upto Pattern M
$RAW_FILTER1=pattern6|pattern7|pattern8|pattern9|pattern10|...upto Pattern N
```

My code is something like below:

```
cat $logFile | egrep "$RAW_FILTER" >> $filesNeedToCheck &
cat $logFile | egrep "$RAW_FILTER1" >> $filesNeedToCheck &
```

wait

Is there any other faster alternative?
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Depending on the load on the server where the logfiles are created, could you tail -f the logs  and pipe it into egrep so that the $filesNeedToCheck are created "live" as the original logfile is written?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Faster alternative of egrep in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955461/faster-alternative-of-egrep-in-perl)

Comment: I can not dig into logs live. So tail is not an option for me.

Comment: I was earliar doing egrep "$RAW_FILTER" $logFile  > $filesNeedToCheck , but after creating two daemon processes it is performing better but still not enough.

Comment: One idea to improve the speed would be to drop the [Useless Use of Cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). It looks horribly inefficient. Another idea would be to actually show the regexes you are using so we can see if they are inefficient.

Comment: How much parallel processing could log storage bear with?

Comment: I have 1 log file which I cannot split. Server has enough memory to bear multiple threads.

Comment: It's not memory but `multiple file read/seeks` when run in parallel, **could** even more slow down processing due storage speed limits.

Comment: Well, you can eliminate one process and speed things up a wee bit by getting rid of the [useless cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) you have. This `cat $file | egrep...` can be simplified to `egrep $file`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a log file, perhaps you can split it into smaller chunks and run greps in subprocesses?